# SVN running on RHEL 8 Authentication issue

Tags: centos, ssl, httpd, svn

Good morning,

I support a subversion server running on rhel 8. The engineers check in/out software builds from a CentOS6 desktop. I need to add authentication to the SVN URL because it's wide open. When I install the new SSL cert on the RHEL 8 it installs fine but I don't think the CentOS6 asset likes it because when they try and run CO/CI commands it doesn't work. Seems like the CentOS6 doesn't like the SSL cert. I dont have high expertise in SVN and looking for some assistance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation CentOS 6 have EOL on 30 November 2020. So this machine have pretty old root and intermediate certificates and "do not like" the new SSL certificate of the server.

Migrate to new version of desktop or modify the commands to accept implicitly the certificate.

Comment: Or install the newer root certificates on the desktops.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, if OP can find them.... :)